# Who was the first Headmaster of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

1. Which of the four founders was the Headmaster of Hogwarts? (if any of the four?)
2. If there was no Headmaster at that time, who was the very first Headmaster?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**None of the four Founders were ever head teacher, only ever professors.**

This comes from an article on *The Leaky Cauldron* describing the opening of the Harry Potter amusement park:

> J.K. Rowling's influence is all over the attraction, from the sparkling dialogue (screenwriter Steve Kloves is also apparent here) on portraits and characters, to small story touches (such as the fact that one statue is of Hogwarts' first headmaster: the founders were professors, none was ever a headmaster) that dot the attraction.
>
> — [*Wizarding World of Harry Potter Grand Opening June 18*, The Leaky Cauldron (March 2010)](http://web.archive.org/web/20100328114838/http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2010/3/25/wizarding-world-of-harry-potter-to-open-june-18-details-about-hogwarts-emerge)

However, I don't know anything more than that. Possibly somebody who’s been to the park can tell us if the statue sheds any light on it.

According to the [HP Wiki article](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/First_Headmaster_of_Hogwarts), a group of girls are studying the statue in the second film. The picture is of a male teacher. However, I haven’t gone back to check this scene, and I don’t know what they’re basing this claim (that the statue is the first headmaster) on.

Comment: and who was the second one?

Answer (score 19):

The image below shows a close up of the statue identified as being "[The First Headmaster of Hogwarts](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/First_Headmaster_of_Hogwarts#cite_note-LTC-0)". It appears several times in the potter films (always in the background, unnamed + unmentioned) and is on display at the Wizard World of Potter theme park.

In answer to the second part of your question, as @alexwlchan has already noted, [the blurb for the Potter theme park states](http://web.archive.org/web/20100328114838/http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2010/3/25/wizarding-world-of-harry-potter-to-open-june-18-details-about-hogwarts-emerge) that **none** of the illustrious four founders ended up being the Headmaster of the school:

> *J.K. Rowling's influence is all over the attraction, from the
>   sparkling dialogue (screenwriter Steve Kloves is also apparent here)
>   on portraits and characters, to small story touches **(such as the fact
>   that one statue is of Hogwarts' first headmaster: the founders were
>   professors, none was ever a headmaster)** that dot the attraction.*

[image]

Comment: Did you go to the theme park and take that photo just to get rep for this answer?

Comment: @randal'thor - No, but the park is on google streetview if you want to go on an interactive  tour.

Comment: Aha! Very nice one :-) I've used the same trick in writing novels: it's a great trick if you want to accurately describe a real place you've never been to.

Answer (score 6):

The name of the first Headmaster is [unknown](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/First_Headmaster_of_Hogwarts), we only know that he **wasn't** a founder, was male and he was ruling the Hogwarts in the early XI century.

Comment: @DVK have you tried clicking the link? ;)